# rails 時間分秒の表示方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### やりたいこと

hour:1 minute:2 second:3 とデータがある場合　→　viewで`1時間2分3秒`と表示したい

### 分岐条件

hourはnilの可能性があるので、hourがnilの場合は時間は表示させない。
minute,secondは値が入っている。

### 質問

普通にifで条件分岐させるやり方しか思いつかないのですが、メソッドなどでスッキリ実装させる方法はないでしょうか。

### コード

```
  unless result.run_hour.nil?
    hour = result.run_hour.to_s + "時間"
  else
    hour = ""
  end

  unless result.run_minute.nil?
    minute = result.run_minute.to_s + "分"
  else
    minute = ""
  end

  unless result.run_second.nil?
    second = result.run_second.to_s + "秒"
  else
    second = ""
  end

  hour + minute + second
```

Comment: 「1時間2分3秒」の2と3の数字を全角から半角に修正しました。

Comment: @manche 問題が解決したのでしたら、[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)することができます :)

Answer (score 1):

スッキリしてるかどうかわかりませんが、こんな感じでどうでしょう。

```
[hour,minute,second].zip(["時","分","秒"]).select(&:first).join
```

Comment: さっそくの回答ありがとうございます。
目から鱗のやり方で。。。


select(&:first)


ここのコードの意味がググっても不明でした。
ご教示いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: `select(&:first)` は `select{|obj| obj.first}` と同じ意味です。ここでの `obj` は `[hour, "時"]` 等の2要素の配列なので、その最初の要素が真のもの(nilで無いもの)を選択しているということになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
相当スッキリしました。

Answer (score 0):

こういう書き方もできます。

```
"#{hour&.to_s&.+'時間'}#{minute&.to_s&.+'分'}#{second&.to_s&.+'秒'}"
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。  

hour&.to_s&.
二つ目の&.はなぜ必要なのでしょうか。
最初の&.だけでは、ダメなのでしょうか。

Comment: やってみれば分かると思いますが、`hour`がnilのときに例外が発生してしまうからです。